# how to lapply to one column in a list of data tables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of `dt` with same structure, some columns are `numeric` some `characters`.

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c(1:5), y = "test")  
dt2 <- data.table(x = c(1:5), y = "test")  
mylist <- list(A = dt1, B = dt2)
```

I want to apply a function, say `sum` or `mean` that cannot be applied across the whole datatable because there are some `character` columns.

I have tried different combinations of `lapply(mylist$y,sum)` or `lapply(mylist[2],sum)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (using valid syntax) and show the exact desired result.

Comment: Does for example `lapply(mylist, function(i) sum(i[,.(x)]))` give the desired result?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus yes it does!

Comment: @Qaswed corrected error

Comment: It's still not clear to me, what you want to achive by `lapply(mylist$y,sum)`. Do you want to now how often `"test"`is found in the elements of the list? "to apply a function, [...] that doesn't work on a `character` column" is a futile aim. To do something that doesn't work, won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function inside `lapply` in which you subset and perform the needed calculation (promoting my comment to an answer):

```
lapply(mylist, function(i) i[, sum(x)])
# or:
lapply(mylist, function(i) sum(i[["x"]]))
```

which gives:

```
$A
[1] 76

$B
[1] 99
```

Another example giving you the number of unique y-values for `x > 3`:

```
lapply(mylist, function(i) i[x>3, uniqueN(y)])
```

which gives:

```
$A
[1] 10

$B
[1] 14
```

---

Used data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c(1:5), y = letters)  
dt2 <- data.table(x = c(1:7), y = letters)
mylist <- list(A = dt1, B = dt2)
```

Comment: I'd prefer `lapply(mylist, function(i) i[, sum(x)])` or `lapply(mylist, function(i) sum(i[["x"]]))`.

Comment: @Roland I think this is more clear. Is there a way to concatenate another operation, say a division or multiplication?

Comment: @Roland Thanx, that's indeed a better way. Corrected now.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus great, that's really useful. And how to concatenate operations, for example lapply(mylist, function(i) sum(i[["x"]])/15)

Comment: @user4050 yes, you can use that as well

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus brilliant. The only confusing thing is why lapply(mylist, function(i) i[sum(y)]) does not work

Comment: @user4050 you need a comma before `sum`, see also the [introduction vignette of the `data.table` package](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

I really think the purrr package makes these problems easier to think about by letting you break the problem up into bite sized pieces:

```
library(purrr)
dt1 <- data_frame(x = c(1:5), y = letters[1:5])  
dt2 <- data_frame(x = c(1:5), y = letters[1:5])  
mylist <- list(A = dt1, B = dt2)

map(mylist, "y") %>% 
  map(length)
```

You can also use something like this to apply a function conditionally

```
map(mylist, ~map_if(., is.numeric, sum))
```

Comment: ok that seems to work, too bad i have to rely on an external package. Would you know how to subset based based each data table in the list based on a value, for example x>3 in my case.

Comment: Yup, you can use any predicate function in `map_if` you just might need to call it as an anonymous function, or define it elsewhere. 
`purrr` is a pretty good external package to use, mostly because it has type-safe alternatives to the apply family of functions.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use nested `lapply()` functions like so:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c(1:5), y = letters[1:5])  
dt2 <- data.table(x = c(6:10), y = letters[1:5])  
mylist <- list(A = dt1, B = dt2) 

lapply(lapply(mylist, function(x) x[[1]]), mean)

# $A
# [1] 3

# $B
# [1] 8
```

Many options here it looks like. With my code, it might be interesting to see what `lapply()` returns and how the other `lapply()` deals with it to understand why it works.

Comment: yes many good examples, what exactly does the [[1]] in your example?

Comment: This is wasteful (and slow for large lists).

Comment: I am not sure on the full semantics of the `[[ ]]` brackets in R, but I use them to select i-th element of a list. `mylist[[2]]` would give the second element used to make `mylist`. I agree that it is wasteful and impractical, but I found that it helps me understand what the program is actually doing. In practice, most other methods would be more appropriate.